# How do I get a CustomStringConvertible description from this enum?

Tags: swift, enums

I have the following enum

```
enum Properties: CustomStringConvertible {
    case binaryOperation(BinaryOperationProperties),
    brackets(BracketsProperties),
    chemicalElement(ChemicalElementProperties),
    differential(DifferentialProperties),
    function(FunctionProperties),
    number(NumberProperties),
    particle(ParticleProperties),
    relation(RelationProperties),
    stateSymbol(StateSymbolProperties),
    symbol(SymbolProperties)
}
```

and the structs all look like this

```
struct BinaryOperationProperties: Decodable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let operation: String
    var description: String { return operation }
}
```

So how do I make that enum conform to `CustomStringConvertible`? I tried with a simple getter but obviously that calls itself and I'd like to call the specific struct's instead.

Bonus points: does an enum defined like that have a name?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Such an enum is called *enum with associated values*.

I'd implement `description` by manually switching over the cases:

```
extension Properties: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .binaryOperation(let props):
            return "binaryOperation(\(props))"
        case .brackets(let props):
            return "brackets(\(props))"
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Edit: an alternative is to use Swift's `Mirror` reflection API. The enum case of an instance is listed as the mirror's child and you can print its label and value like this:*

```
extension Properties: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        var result = ""
        for child in mirror.children {
            if let label = child.label {
                result += "\(label): \(child.value)"
            } else {
                result += "\(child.value)"
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

*(This is a generic solution that should be usable for many types, not just enums. You'll probably have to add some line breaks for types that have more than a single child.)*

---

*Edit 2: `Mirror` is also what `print` and `String(describing:)` use for types that don't conform to `Custom[Debug]StringConvertible`. [You can check out the source code here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c272d41e2f392d2b97c9bd55d819be67912f01d0/stdlib/public/core/OutputStream.swift#L253-L344).*

Comment: I ended up using the first option as the output is more compact for what I need, but thanks for being thorough!

Comment: Can this `description` String be accessed from Obj-C ?